# Typescript possibly undefined even with assertion

Tags: javascript, typescript

Code in question:

```
if (farm) {
    animals = [...Array(farm.attributes.animalCount)].map(() => (
       <AnimalItemPlaceholder />
   ));
}
```

Error:

```
const farm: undefined
Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

I am new to TypeScript and can't seem to find out how to handle this particular error. My farm variable has the possibility of being undefined, since it is fetched after my component has mounted. I just can't suppress this error, despite me asserting the value before using it. I also tried `null` on the type, but the error is the same except rather than `undefined` it is now `null`.

Guidance?

EDIT:

Farm type is declared like so

```js
interface IState {
  farm: IFarm | undefined;
}
```

Comment: Where do you initialize `farm`? What is the type you are giving?

Comment: What specific line is it pointing to? TypeScript is very good at type guards (that's not an assertion, it's a type guard). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. Please note both the "minimal" and the "reproducible," both are important. :-)

Comment: The error is interesting, because it's saying that `farm` has the type `undefined` (not `Something|undefined`). That suggests `farm` isn't what you're expecting it to be.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a **very** active place. When you post a question (or an answer!). please *stick around* so you can deal with anything that comes up in the comments.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have updated my question with the declaration of the farm type. I got pulled into a meeting right after posting, my apologies.

Worth me noting that farm is 100% defined because the state is set in an ajax call right after the component is mounted (not that it matters as I am checking for null/undefined).

Comment: @Gibbo - Ah, meetings. :-) Again, please update your question with a [mcve], we can't help you with only what's above. Again, please specify **exactly** what line the error is pointing to. Also tell us how the `farm` constant is initialized. *"...because the state is set in an ajax call right after the component is mounted..."* That means on first `render`, it will definitely be `undefined`. As you say, you have a guard there. Guards **do** work, so something is going on that we can't see above.

Comment: Alrighty, I shall update the OP. Sorry for terrible example! :D. Might take a bit, stay tuned :).